# Looking for the most common item in a list and random items are returned instead

Tags: prolog

I'm looking for the most common item in a list but I'm getting a lot of random results instead. Not sure why.

This is my code:

```
find_most_common([], []).
find_most_common(List, E) :-
 msort(List, [H|T]),
 find_most_common(T, H, H, 1, 0, E).

find_most_common([], H, _, C1, C2, H) :- 
 C1 >= C2.
find_most_common([], _, X, C1, C2, X) :- 
 C1 < C2. 

find_most_common([H|T], H, L, C1, C2, E) :-
 find_most_common(T, H, L, C1 + 1, C2, E).


find_most_common([X|T], H, L, C1, C2, E) :-
( 
 C1 > C2 ->  find_most_common(T, X, H, 1, C1, E) ; 
 find_most_common(T, X, L, 1, C2, E)
).
```

This is the result I get:

```
?- find_most_common([a,b,b,a,a], E).
E = a ;
E = a ;
E = b ;
E = a ;
E = b ;
E = a ;
E = b ;
E = b ;
false.
```

I should be getting this instead:

```
?- find_most_common([a,b,b,a,a], E).
E = a ;
false.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Prolog to stop searching for alternatives using "cut".

For example, if you add the following "cut" to this clause...

```
find_most_common([H|T], H, L, C1, C2, E) :- !,
 find_most_common(T, H, L, C1 + 1, C2, E).
```

It only finds one answer for the inputs you have given.

What is supposed to happen in this case?

> find_most_common([a,a,a,b,b,b], E).

Should it return a or b? It will currently return b.

### Tip

If you run your program using `trace.` you can see which clause is being "redone" when you ask to do a redo...

(This is without adding the extra cut)

```
[trace] 3 ?- find_most_common([a,b,b,a,a], E).
   Call: (6) find_most_common([a, b, b, a, a], _G3171) ? creep
   Call: (7) msort([a, b, b, a, a], [_G3251|_G3252]) ? creep
   Exit: (7) msort([a, b, b, a, a], [a, a, a, b, b]) ? creep
   Call: (7) find_most_common([a, a, b, b], a, a, 1, 0, _G3171) ? creep
   Call: (8) find_most_common([a, b, b], a, a, 1+1, 0, _G3171) ? creep
   Call: (9) find_most_common([b, b], a, a, 1+1+1, 0, _G3171) ? creep
   Call: (10) 1+1+1>0 ? creep
   Exit: (10) 1+1+1>0 ? creep
   Call: (10) find_most_common([b], b, a, 1, 1+1+1, _G3171) ? creep
   Call: (11) find_most_common([], b, a, 1+1, 1+1+1, _G3171) ? creep
   Call: (12) 1+1>=1+1+1 ? creep
   Fail: (12) 1+1>=1+1+1 ? creep
   Redo: (11) find_most_common([], b, a, 1+1, 1+1+1, _G3171) ? creep
   Call: (12) 1+1<1+1+1 ? creep
   Exit: (12) 1+1<1+1+1 ? creep
   Exit: (11) find_most_common([], b, a, 1+1, 1+1+1, a) ? creep
   Exit: (10) find_most_common([b], b, a, 1, 1+1+1, a) ? creep
   Exit: (9) find_most_common([b, b], a, a, 1+1+1, 0, a) ? creep
   Exit: (8) find_most_common([a, b, b], a, a, 1+1, 0, a) ? creep
   Exit: (7) find_most_common([a, a, b, b], a, a, 1, 0, a) ? creep
   Exit: (6) find_most_common([a, b, b, a, a], a) ? creep
E = a ;
   Redo: (10) find_most_common([b], b, a, 1, 1+1+1, _G3171) ? creep
   Call: (11) 1>1+1+1 ? creep
   Fail: (11) 1>1+1+1 ? creep
   Redo: (10) find_most_common([b], b, a, 1, 1+1+1, _G3171) ? creep
   Call: (11) find_most_common([], b, a, 1, 1+1+1, _G3171) ? creep
   Call: (12) 1>=1+1+1 ? creep
   Fail: (12) 1>=1+1+1 ? creep
   Redo: (11) find_most_common([], b, a, 1, 1+1+1, _G3171) ? creep
   Call: (12) 1<1+1+1 ? creep
   Exit: (12) 1<1+1+1 ? creep
   Exit: (11) find_most_common([], b, a, 1, 1+1+1, a) ? creep
...etc...
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach: iterate elements and find if another element is met more often (note that the comparison is for integers):

```
my-member([X], X).
my-member([_|T], X) :- my-member(T, X).

count-occur([H], X, 0) :- H =\= X.
count-occur([X], X, 1).
count-occur([H|T], X, C) :- 
    ( H =:= X, count-occur(T, X, C1), C is C1 + 1 ); 
    ( H =\= X, count-occur(T, X, C) ). 

most-common(L, E) :- 
    my-member(L, E),
    count-occur(L, E, C),
    not((my-member(L, Y, C1), Y =\= E, C > C1 )).
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my approach

```
most_common([], []).
most_common([H|T], M) :-
    nb_occurences([H|T], [], N),
    sort(N, RS),
    reverse(RS, [Max:I|S]),
    member(Max:M, [Max:I|S]).

nb_occurences([], L, L).
nb_occurences([H|T], L, N) :-
    (   select(I:H, L, L2) ->
        J is I + 1
        ;
        J is 1,
        L2 = L
    ),
    nb_occurences(T, [J:H|L2], N).
```

First, we use `nb_occurences/3` to build a list of pairs `Occurences:Element`. Then we sort those pairs and take the occurence of the last one as a way to select the correct outputs that we retrieve with `member/2`.